# Java Parse according to the specified word

Tags: java

**LogParser.java**

```
package com.mpj.Parallelization;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LogParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File logfile = new File("/C:/ParallelKMeansProject/logs/log.txt");

        try {
            Scanner parserscanner = new Scanner(logfile);

            String nextLine = parserscanner.nextLine();

            String[] logcomponent = nextLine.split(" ");

            String latitude = logcomponent[0];
            String longtitude = logcomponent[1];

            System.out.println(latitude);
            System.out.println(longtitude);

            System.out.println("Next Line: " + nextLine);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**log.txt Content**

> 2017-03-10 12:30:30 DEBUG SerialKMeans:29 -
>
> ======
>
> Number of iterations: 21 Within cluster sum of squared errors:
>   13.902870732812898
>
> Initial starting points (random):
>
> Cluster 0: 41.051205,28.808497 Cluster 1: 41.055391,28.785407 Cluster
>   2: 41.054838,28.802617 Cluster 3: 41.022421,28.788169 Cluster 4:
>   41.024494,28.784099 Cluster 5: 41.018659,28.787669 Cluster 6: 41.040879,28.753359
>
> Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode ...

This like, I have log.txt and logs write side by side and long.

My first question is `System.out.println("Next Line: " + nextLine);`

I didn't see all log with this command line. Log writing ends here (2017-03-10 12:30:30 DEBUG SerialKMeans:29 - )  Does not write more.Logos are all written side by side in txt file. Not the bottom line. But It writes just 2017-03-10 12:30:30 DEBUG SerialKMeans:29 -

My second question; If we solve the first problem, I want to parse to a specific word. How can I do that

Comment: You only read one line `String nextLine = parserscanner.nextLine();`. You should loop to read every line

Comment: Use this to get all lines `while(parserscanner.hasNextLine()){ nextLine = parserscanner.nextLine(); }` , to parse specific pattern you can use scanner's findInLine method or just use string.split line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(logfile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      System.out.println (line);
    }
```

Or if you want to keep your current code, I'd do what @Ömer Erden suggested, using a while loop to iterate through all the lines.